# Laravel Sail 10 + Xdebug + PhpStorm + Mac M1

Tags: laravel, xdebug, laravel-sail, xdebug-3, laravel-octane

I already have a project running on Laravel Sail 10.0 with roadrunner. I tried to configure Xdebug but I can't make it stop on my breakpoints.
Every time I run sail up it PhpStorm create a new tab on debug section called Artisan an a lot of roadrunner-worker tabs

- Laravel octane Sail 10.0 with roadrunner
- Using PHP 8.2
- Macbook Pro M1
- PhpStorm 2022.2.5

.env

```ini
SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE=develop,debug
SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG="client_host=host.docker.internal client_port=9003 idekey=PHPSTORM"
```

PhpStorm Debug config:

[image]

PhpStorm Servers:

[image]

php.ini (maybe this is not necessary?)

[image]

PhpStorm debug tabs:

[image]

When I run `sail test`

[image: Image when I run "sail test"]

I tried several `SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG`

```ini
SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG=docker.for.mac.host.internal
SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG="client_host=172.30.0.1"
SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG="client_host=host.docker.internal client_port=9003 idekey=PHPSTORM"
SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG="client_host=docker.for.mac.host.internal client_port=9003 idekey=PHPSTORM"
SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG="client_host=docker.for.mac.host.internal remote_port=9003 remote_enable=1"
SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_host=host.docker.internal remote_port=9003 idekey=PHPSTORM"
SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_host=host.docker.internal remote_port=9003 idekey=PHPSTORM"
```

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to put that long config line in 1 variable. Check this link first. https://medium.com/codex/laravel-8-0-sail-xdebug-phpstorm-5cc900e96da4 also: set up your docker settings in your PHPStorn

Comment: Reading that post I figured out that I missed the "PHP_IDE_CONFIG: serverName=Docker" on my docker-compose.yml file. Now It's almost working but after 30 secs the xdebug session ends up. Looks like It create a new roadrunner-worker. Thanks @UnderDog

Comment: what is a `roadrunner-worker`?

Comment: RoadRunner is a high-performance PHP application server, load-balancer, and process manager